# How would one mimic the geom_col() function from the R library ggplot in the Python package Altair?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, altair

I am trying to plot a column graph using Altair, however there is no mark_column() method in Altair. How can I mimic the functionality of geom_col() using Altairs mark_bar() method?

Answer (score 1):

From the [ggplot2 docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html):

> There are two types of bar charts: `geom_bar()` and `geom_col()`. `geom_bar()` makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group (or if the weight aesthetic is supplied, the sum of the weights). If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use `geom_col()` instead.

It sounds like the difference between them is not the mark, but what value the marks represent. In Altair, the value represented by a mark is defined via an encoding.

So Altair's version of `geom_bar()` might look something like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
  'category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
})

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
  x='category:N',
  y='count():Q'
)
```

or, for `geom_bar()` with a weight aesthetic,

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
  'category': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
  'weights': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2]
})

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
  x='category:N',
  y='sum(weights):Q'
)
```

Altair's version of `geom_col()` might look something like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
  'category': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  'value': [4.1, 6.3, 2.2]
})

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
  x='category:N',
  y='value:Q'
)
```